# How to place a Textview below to the each Imageview?

Tags: xml

I struck in layout weight concept that need to place a text below to the each imageview and i tried many methods in weight concept but textView is going somewhere.I attached my xml here and if anyone have suggestion give me a idea to solve this.Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/topBar"
          style="@style/IconBar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="90dp"
          android:baselineAligned="true"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:weightSum="4" >


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/glow" 
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:src="@drawable/glow"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageLabel"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Israel News"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/glow" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/place"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/glow" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/account"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/glow" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/accounts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/glow" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where are the textviews?

Comment: @akash93Updated my code

Comment: The `layout_weight` needs to be assigned to a direct child of the `LinearLayout` in this case the `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

To apply TextView under each ImageView, you need a layout as a parent for each TextView and ImageView as a child

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/glow" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:id="@+id/homeText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Email Text"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It was not equally partitioned based on weight and also i want to keep the text below to imageview with some paddingtop